# Failed to prepare device for development error when deploying app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am trying to run my app on a physical device. The applicaiton builds but it doesnt deploy my app to the device.

I get this following error:

This operation can fail if the version of the OS on the device is incompatible with the installed version of Xcode. You may also need to restart your mac and device in order to correctly detect compatibility.

Details:

I have xcode version 13.2.1
device is iphone 11 pro max with ios version 15.6 installed.

I tried to upgrade my xcode to 13.4.1 but on app store there is no button that indicates that i can upgrade.

Things I have tried:

restarting mac
restarting iphone device
closing and reopening xcode
cleaning project and rebuilding.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Download xCode 13.4.1 directly using the link
https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_13.4.1/Xcode_13.4.1.xip

Comment: when clicked - unauthorised page is displayed.